# What Is Best Practice for Return Types using Java Generics and Factory Pattern

Tags: java, generics, jackson

I'm trying to learn to use Generics for the first time, a fairly complex way.  I'm also using Jackson 2 for Deserialization.

I'm casting in my return statements every time.  Can someone tell me if this is wrong? If so, what is a better way to do it?

Here is a simple example class that demonstrates the situation:

```
class ResourceFactory <T extends Resource>{

    List<T> getResources(String path)
    {
        ResourcesResponse rgRes = new ObjectMapper()
        .readValue(response.body().byteStream(), ResourcesResponse.class)

        return (List<T>)rgRes.resources
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Per a comment, here are super-simplified examples of what the other class bodies look like.

```
class ResourceResponse {
    List<Resource> resources
}

class ResourceGeneric extends Resource {
}

class ResourceTypeOne extends Resource {
    public String typeOneOnlyProperty
}

class ResourceTypeTwo extends Resource {
    public String typeTwoOnlyProperty
}
```

Comment: Can you share the definition of `ResourcesResponse` and `Resource`?

Comment: I've added some mocks.  If you want to see the Jackson annotations, I can mock those up as well, however there isn't a problem with the Jackson Deserialization.  I'm just trying to determine if casting as (List<T>) on every return statement is the best thing.

Comment: `ResourceResponse` should be `ResourceResponse<T extends Resource>`. And resources should be a `List<T>`. And you should pass a TypeReference<ResourceResponse<T>> as argument.

Comment: ResourceResponse<T extends Resource> doesn't seem to work. Cannot understand why. It says it expects > after T, and underlines Resource. Same on method signatures.

Comment: Have to add public in front. I didn't notice because i am using groovy and the public is usually implied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jackson can support generic types if used correctly. Here's how I would do it:

```
class ResourcesResponse<T extends Resource> {
    List<T> resources;
}

class ResourceFactory<T extends Resource> {
    // Either of these should work; pick your constructor
    private JavaType responseType;
    private TypeReference<ResourcesResponse<T>> responseType;

    // Option A
    // Involves some boilerplate, but keeps the constructor simple
    // Use: new ResourceFactory<ResourceTypeOne>(ResourceTypeOne.class)
    ResourceFactory(Class<T> resourceType) {
        this.responseType = TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
               .constructParametricType(ResourcesResponse.class, resourceType);
    }

    // Option B
    // Cleaner internally, but exposes implementation details
    // Use: new ResourceFactory<ResourceTypeOne>(new TypeReference<ResourcesResponse<ResourceTypeOne>>() {})
    ResourceFactory(TypeReference<ResourcesResponse<T>> responseType) {
        this.responseType = responseType;
    }

    List<T> getResources(String path)
    {
        ResourcesResponse<T> rgRes = new ObjectMapper()
        .readValue(response.body().byteStream(), responseType);

        return rgRes.resources;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Still reading it.  Did you mean to name this variable something else:  private TypeReference<ResourcesResponse<T>> responseType;

Comment: It looks like the major difference in your approaches is that you're requiring a class name to be passed in as a parameter in parens() as opposed to passing in the type information via arrows <>.  I'm guessing this is the only way to tell Jackson exactly what class to deserialize as dynamically (something you can't do with just the "T" symbol).   This is actually particularly helpful for me, because I have a few cases where the JSON responses I'm getting contain no good indication of type, so I have to write a selector, and pass in a classname. This helps me with that a lot.

Comment: Chosing this as the best answer because it also accounts for the Jackson component of my scenario.  Very thorough!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, now a bit confused about the responseType. I'm hoping that ResourceResponse.class can point to a base class, and that resourceType can be a more specific subclass of that base class, which Jackson should deserialize to. Is this correct/possible?     I have polymorphic deserialization working in other cases, but it's based on @JsonTypeInfo annotations.

Comment: Also, constructParametricType is deprecated.  Can you edit your answer to use the newer method?   https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html

Comment: Another problem.  This one more fundamental.  The following class definitions looses intellisense on "resources".  It does not show the properties and methods of "resources" like it should :    class ResourcesResponse<T extends Resource> {
    List<T> resources;
}

Comment: @solvingJ 1. I named them the same because either one would work with the `getResources()` implementation. 2. `resourceType` is meant to identify the type of `T`. That's all we need to construct the type of `ResourcesResponse<T>`. 3. I used the deprecated version because the newer one doesn't exist in earlier versions. The new one should look like this: `constructParameterizedType(ResourcesResponse.class, ResourcesResponse.class, resourceType)`. 4. I can't help you with intellisense. From what I've seen, Eclipse knows how to handle it. Anyway, I wouldn't call this a "fundamental" problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Getting closer now. Finally hitting the deserialization problems I was expecting. I've added Jackson annotations and a generic class.  ...... Current problem:  When calling: new ResourceFactory<ResourceTypeOne>(ResourceTypeOne.class) I get the following:  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Problem deserializing property 'typeOneOnlyProperty' (expected type: [simple type, class java.lang.String]; actual type: java.lang.String), problem: Can not set java.lang.String field ResourceTypeOne to ResourceGeneric

Comment: Ok, the annotations on the base class were apparently conflicting with manually setting the type.  They were invalid anyway, so I've removed them and it's working.  However, I can see a future case when it would be nice to be able to use the annotations (@JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubType) but still be able to override the target manually during instantiation.  Maybe it's possible with more reading.

Answer (score 1):

Because of type erasure the fail-fast technique is to pass the Resource child class:

```
public <T extends Resource> List<T> getResources(Class<T> resourceType, String path)
{
    ResourcesResponse rgRes = new ObjectMapper()
    .readValue(response.body().byteStream(), ResourcesResponse.class)

    return Collections.checkedList(rgRes.resources, resourceType);
}
```

This ensures that with such unsafe casts as your code had, no values of *other* classes are added.

This does not "check" the original list

```
rgRes.resources.forEach(res -> resourceType.cast(res))
```

And this is not a simple cast.

Comment: I see your point, i'm actually working on implementing JB Nizets comments at the moment, which is to go upstream and change ResourceResponse to ResourceResponse<T extends Resource> , and the resources from List<Resource> to List<T Extends Resource> ......   Followup question, the part   "List<T extends Resource>"  never works for me on a method, I can only seem to use extends at the class level.  It says it's expecting > after T, and three other red lines show up.   Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Example:  What is wrong with this definition:    public class Box {
    public List<T extends Number> inspect(T t){
        
    }
}

Comment: I had an error in the generics part, so do: `public <T ...> List<T> inspect(...)`

Comment: Thanks, that part is working now. I think my problem was that I'm using groovy, and you need to include public before the <T extends Resource>. In groovy, public is normally implied.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your comment: "This is not a simple cast?"

Comment: Upvoting this as a perfectly fine and working answer, and it highlights the need for type safety.  It shows the checkedList method which I was unaware of.  Also, it does provide a safer/better generics signature to the method, which is what I was originally looking for. Although, I think it needs the word public in front.   Thanks very much!